# Cloudwatch Logs insights - Count 500 & total requests in the same query for Visualization

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am building a cloud watch dashboard to show the availability of our service. For this metrics, I need to get the number of 500 errors and the total requests. I have the below Logs Insights Query.

```
fields resourcePath, userAgent
| filter resourcePath = "myService/orders/{id}"
| stats bin(1w), count(status) by status
```

Produce output like

```
status bin(4w) count(status)
---------------------------
500             7
200             90
```

But, when I click the Visualization, it shows `The data is not suitable for a line chart.` . I need to show two lines one for 200 and one for 500. Is it possible in a single query? Thanks in advance.

I can't use the API Gateway's metrics as I need to manually filter few calls from specific userAgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualizations only support a single bin operator in the `by` expression.

Give this a try:

```
fields resourcePath, userAgent
| filter resourcePath = "myService/orders/{id}"
| fields (status == 200) as is200, (status == 500) as is500
| stats sum(is200) as total200, sum(is500) as total500 by bin(1w)
```